# Why Velocity is referred as momentum?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, momentum, navier-stokes

In many text books the velocity is referred to as a linear momentum which is being convected.

For example the table in the following [page](https://books.google.be/books?id=RvBZ-UMpGzIC&lpg=PP1&dq=an%20introduction%20to%20computational%20fluid%20dynamics%20the%20finite%20volume%20method&pg=PA13#v=onepage&q&f=false)

My old conception is that the momentum or more precisely momentum per unit volume = **$\rho.u$** and this quantity is being convected by velocity

Can anyone clarify this point?

Best regards.

EDIT:

I have found the answer for my question. As I can't answer the question I will put the answer here:

When fluid flows through a surface, it carries not only mass, but momentum as well. The momentum flux can be described as:

momentum flux = (mass flux) × (momentum /mass).

Momentum/mass is simply the velocity, so **the velocity is referred to as momentum (per unit mass)**. Moreover we can consider this quantity as a passive scalar that is convected by mass flux, this is the analogous, for instance, to the mass or heat convection by bulk fluid motion.

Comment: What do you mean, *"velocity is referred to as a linear momentum"*? *Momentum (density)* is velocity times mass (density), and that's precisely what $\rho\cdot u$ is. I don'T know what you're asking.

Comment: That link leads me to the cover of a book.

Comment: @ACuriousMind, Yes I Know that ρ⋅u  is the momentum density. The problem is that in many text books (see the link above) velocity ALONE is referred to as a linear momentum. Another quotation from my lecture notes "in the momentum equation we recognize the linear momentum in x-direction (i.e. u) which is treated similar to the passive scalar in the convection term of a conventional convection diffusion equation". So why u is equal to x-momentum and why it is treated as passive scalar?

Comment: @ Kyle Kanos, Sorry for that, the table in page 13, hope you can find it.

Comment: Is this strictly in incompressible fluids? And where does convection come into this?

Comment: I should correct myself. I do not have a 'see inside' option for the book you linked, it is just the cover & brief description. I cannot see page 13, or any other page for that matter.